# How to do overwriting of a file opened in append mode, in the subsequent runs

Tags: python

I have opened my file in append mode and it works fine, but when I run the program again it doesn't overwrites the previous content. I am not able to figure out where I went wrong. This may be a very basic question , but I am new to python. Please help.

```
with open(Result,"a") as f:
      csv_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
      csv_writer.writerow((fn1,fn2))
```

I need to append the contents but also needed to overwrite it when the program is run for the next time.

Comment: Why did you open in append mode if you want to overwrite the old contents? Append mode is specifically the "please don't overwrite the old contents" option.

Comment: I tried opening in write mode too.But when I opened in write mode it writes only the last result I needed.@Sukrit Kalra

Comment: Then your problem is probably that in your code, you're *re*-opening the file for every line. Don't do that; open it once, keep it open, and make all your `writerow` calls with one writer. Only close it once you're all done writing. If you have a `with` in a loop, you probably need to put the `with` around the loop instead.

Comment: Are you opening the file more than once in your script? If so, open in write mode the first time, and append for the others. Or, open once in write mode and only close it once you've done all the writing you need.

Answer (score 1):

To overwrite the previous contents, open the file in `"w"` mode. (Write Mode)

```
with open(Result,"w") as f:
      csv_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
      csv_writer.writerow((fn1,fn2))
```

[Read more about `open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)